# Binding not working with row header on DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row

I have this and I know the binding work because I use it to populate the datagrid, but when I try to populate the row header it doesn't seem to work.

```
        <DataGrid Margin="150,50,150,50" x:Name="GridBinding" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Month]}" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" SelectionUnit="Cell" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Oct." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[October].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nov." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[November].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dec." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[December].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Jan." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[January].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Feb." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[February].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mar." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[March].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Apr." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[April].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="May" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[May].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="June" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[June].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="July" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[July].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Aug." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[August].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sep." Binding="{Binding Path=Element[September].Value}" Width="*" Foreground="Black"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Element[Depth].Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRowHeader}}"  Foreground="#9493CF" FontSize="16" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: `DataGridRowHeader` doesn't have an "Element" property which you can bind to.  What are you really trying to refer to?

Comment: added the whole code, and I'm trying to do the same as I did in the Datagrid.columns

Comment: Again, you're binding to `DataGridRowHeader`, which doesn't have an "Element" property to which you can bind.  You said it was working to populate the `DataGrid`?  I'm not sure why that was working, since `DataGrid` doesn't have an "Element" property either, but you could try `AncestorType=DataGrid` for the `TextBlock.Text`...

Comment: Didn't work out :/, do you have any other idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doesn't require the `Ancestor`  since the `RowHeader` also has the same `DataContext` where the normal column has. So you could directly get the `Element` Property there.

[image]

But in your case its not working means.. you might be gone with some thing wrong. Anyway the below code will help you to resolve.

```
 <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Element[Depth].Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"  Foreground="#9493CF" FontSize="16" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

Comment: I've tried that, that's why I've tried to get it to the ancestor who have the property, but, anyway, It's not working :/